# Why does "params object[]" need passing as "new object[] { parameters }" for Com Method?

Tags: c#, object, parameters, com, codedom

I've found lots of info on passing parameters to methods and found that having the method use `params Object[] args` to be a great (and sometimes only) way to do this.

i.e. sample method:

```
public void someMethod(params object[] args)
{
      //do something
}
```

But when passing the parameter object like this to a Com Method, it doesn't work:

```
object[] passParameters = new object[2];
passParameters[0] = "test1";
passParameters[1] = "test2";

//Calling method compiled with with CodeDom
MethodInfo method = classObject.GetType().GetMethod("someMethod");
object dynamicOutput = method.Invoke(classObject, passParameters);
```

For it to work, I have found that I need to pass the parameter object as a new Object:

```
object dynamicOutput = method.Invoke(classObject,(new object[] { passParameters });
```

Can anyone please explain to me why I need to do this and what the reasoning is behind it? Thanks.

Comment: Then why use `params` in the first place - this misses the entire point of it

Comment: Your first example *does* work, though.  Are you getting an error message?

Comment: I'm not getting an error. `someMethod(passParameters);` works fine.

Comment: Or did you want the array to be passed as a single object?

Comment: My crystal ball says that you forgot to tell us that "someMethod" is actually a COM interface method and its argument is passed ByRef.

Comment: Hans - You are absolutely correct. I'll update my question now to avoid the use of the crystal ball any more!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've come to realise that the original `passParameters` object in the example contains two elements, as we know:

```
passParameters[0] = "test1";
passParameters[1] = "test2";
```

However, when the array is passed to the Com method, it requires being passed as so:

```
new object[] { passParameters })
```

My understanding of this is, that it creates a new object array which has put the existing 'passParameters' array into its first element [0] (effectively creating a new 2d array):

```
passParameters[0][0] = "test1";
passParameters[0][1] = "test2";
```

The method `MethodInfo` class in my question, required a single object passed to the `Invoke` method, which meant that the original 'passParameters' object with its two elements had too many arguments. By passing it inside a new object, this passes all of the elements as a single object, but containing an array of those parameters.

Answer (score 0):

They don't. You can just use them as

```
someMethod("test1", "test2", ... )
```

**BUT**. If you're creating an **array** beforehand, it has to be passed differently, as you encountered